# VPN bandwidth usage logging

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, vpn, openvpn

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server running OpenVPN and expect to have 10 or so unique clients using it at any given time. I will be issuing unique certificates to each device. Is there a straightforward way to monitor how much bandwidth each user consumes in a given time period, possibly broken down by specific certificate used to authenticate their session?